# typescript declare a type with many properties of same type

Tags: typescript

I have a type for Theme who will contain doozens of colors, all are strings.

Is there a way to shorten this ? like saying that all properties of ThemeColors are strings?
thanks

```
type ThemeColors = {
  white: string;
  black: string;
  grey: string;
  ligthGrey: string;
  headerBackground: string;
  headerWhite: string;
  redError: string;
  greenSuccess: string;
  yellow: string;
  orange: string;
  peach: string;
  pink: string;
  purpleLight: string;
  purple: string;
  violet: string;
  blue: string;
};
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you actually care about the particular keys, you could define them as a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types):

```
type ThemeKeys = "white" | "black" | "grey" | "ligthGrey" |
  "headerBackground" | "headerWhite" | "redError" |
  "greenSuccess" | "yellow" | "orange" | "peach" | "pink"
  | "purpleLight" | "purple" | "violet" | "blue";
```

And then define `ThemeColors` as a simple [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over those keys with the property type of `string`:

```
type ThemeColors = { [P in ThemeKeys]: string };
```

which displays as

```
/* type ThemeColors = {
    white: string;
    black: string;
    grey: string;
    ligthGrey: string;
    headerBackground: string;
    headerWhite: string;
    redError: string;
    greenSuccess: string;
    yellow: string;
    orange: string;
    peach: string;
    pink: string;
    purpleLight: string;
    purple: string;
    violet: string;
    blue: string;
} */
```

That's also equivalent to `Record<ThemeKeys, string>` using [the `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type).

---

If you *don't* care about the keys and just want to say that whatever the keys are, the properties are `strings`, then you want to use an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) like

```
type ThemeColors = { [k: string]: string };
```

which is equivalent to `Record<string, string>`, as described in the other answers to this question.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.0.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFhAthA0hEBnKBeKAiAdzgEtgI8oAffAIwBsBDAYwGsLq8BzAJ3XfzrFOwOAHFeIdgCgo+BAwAmEbgCFmLHgHsArgDsF-PPKXcA6iTKHeCgKLdum7tNldeEXQGVtTJhAwZDEAg6Ok0CQ0cGXU5yKnxIZjhDMGJdNhk4vDBtbjA6CAAZIThgZJy82I4AN2JNfNLM+m1yAG4pKVBIWARkAGE6xyxcAG8oAG0ABShU7qRUdAwAXQAuKAxgblTOKABfKQB6ACooTuh4Of7Q7iGoYYzZIlIIVfXN6LbZWXp1F42tj8+PHQvzenABskEwjEEhB-3uUGMyjUrC0egUsPe8MRZgszzWf0xnyg1jsDm4GLB8KB7i8Pj8GAp4KgQRCYUZ8Mi0TxrzhRISTDg7L5qRYQs+2Vy+SKnBKYtkEoqcqgNTqEGASqa3IJlJ2UEO+yAA)

Comment: brillant . thank you ! did you know if i can put test on the value of color to be length=== 7 chars please ?

Comment: There is no specific type in TS corresponding to "strings of length 7"; you could make a generic constraint and a helper function to do this, but I'm afraid it's out of scope for this question and the comments herein. Followup questions should probably be written up as new question posts (after an appropriate search for existing relevant q/a pairs).

Comment: oky, yes i should open a new question, TS  provide so much new functionality over js, i shoud get a book about it to discover some of them. i searched for this but didn't found anything easy to implement yet. thanks for your time and superb answer any way. i used it :)